# Symfony (doctrine) try to insert null related object while saving

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I work on symfony 1.4 (doctrine) project. I've added relation to my sfGuardUserProfile model:

```
    sfGuardUserProfile:
      tableName: sf_guard_user_profile
      columns:
        id:                     { type: integer(20), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
        user_id:                { type: integer(20), notnull: true }
        username:               { type: string(128), notnull: false }
        ...
city:                   { type: string(255) }
        ...
      relations:
        User:
          class: sfGuardUser
          foreign: id
          local: user_id
          type: one
          onDelete: cascade
          foreignType: one
          foreignAlias: Profile
        ...
        RelatedCity:
          class:          City
          local:          city
          foreign:        woeid
          onDelete:       cascade
          type:           one
```

Now, when I try to save sfGuardUserProfile object (city value is null) it tries to create new record in cities table with all fields null and I get an sql exception `Column country_id cannot be null`. country_id is a field in city table (and model). How to prevent inserting this null city object?

Screenshot of exception: http://screencast.com/t/Lw4m909L7Y8w

Maybe this will help: https://db.tt/0JBx4S3P 
it is screenshot of sfGuardUserProfile object fields. Strenge is that in RelatedCity object there is null value on country_id (not DoctrineNull)

Comment: If you use phpMyadmin, you can check box `NULL` or `EMPTY` near your column name

Comment: that's not a problem.

Comment: then i'm going to leave you alone with your question  (: Good luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem